# Correct 2D representation in a message string

Tags: string-manipulation, boxes, message-coding

`Message` knows how to convert an expression (taken as an argument) into a string before it is spliced into an actual message:

If I run the following in my terminal and in the front end

```
temp::mystr = "The symbol: `1`";
Message[temp::mystr, Pi];
```

the symbol `Pi` is rendered differently:

[image]

[image]

I would like to directly enter an expression into the message string so that it renders appropriately depending on where it is issued: (in the terminal -> `OutputForm`, or in the front end notebook -> `StandardForm`).  `temp::mystr2 = "The symbol: \!\(Pi\)";` doesn't render correctly in the front end, while `temp::mystr2 = "The symbol: \[Pi]";` renders incorrectly in the terminal.  Does anyone know how to do it correctly [I need a solution that works in *Mathematica* 8 through 11]?

Comment: Something to try on both cases: `MeijerG::usage`.

Comment: Looking for existing examples that work I tried `Pi::usage` and found that it is simply `"Pi is \[Pi], ..."` and prints like that in the terminal.  I'm not sure this is possible within a String alone.  It's easy elsewhere using `Format` but I cannot see how to apply that to messages.

Comment: @J.M. I tried that already, but that is not instructive because the boxes are already hard coded into usage messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to define what you mean by "rendering correctly", and (b) what is "a terminal".  But I'm guessing your issue really has little to do with typesetting as such.

If `"The symbol: \!\(Pi\)"`, or even the string `"\[Pi]"`, doesn't render with the glyph of U+03C0, then your problem is the value of `$CharacterEncoding` is for a character set (perhaps "WindowsANSI", more formally known as Windows Code Page 1252) that doesn't include that character.  So, you'll need to (i) change the value of $CharacterEncoding which does include it, say, UTF-8, (ii) use a terminal font which includes that glyph, and (iii) make sure that the character encoding of your terminal is consistent with (i) and (ii).  (My understanding of the Windows console is that (ii) automatically determines (iii), though I'm hardly an expert in the Windows API.  In most Unix consoles these are independent settings.)

Now, as for the *symbol* Pi, it has an `OutputForm` formatting rule which is to format as `Pi` rather than `\[Pi]` (a decision which not doubt dates to V1, when the latter would have been almost universally useless).  If you want override how that appears as an argument to a message, you'll need to use `$MessagePrePrint` or a custom handler in the code issueing the message to tweak its appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the form

```
Message[temp::mystr, "\:03c0"];
```

will give the same output

> `temp::mystr: The symbol: π`

in both a notebook and when running a kernel in Terminal.

#### Edit

This is in response to @Mr.Wizard comment.

I don't understand what you are saying. On my system it has nothing to do with `Message`. Here is a Terminal window capture.

[image: terminal]

I am running OS X, so a terminal session is talking to a Mathematica kernel through Free-BSD Unix. Perhaps it is system dependent, but there seems to be no problem on a Unix-based system.

#### Edit 2

Also please note that for me "The symbol: \[Pi]" does render correctly in Terminal.

[image: terminal_2]

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and I don't interpret the question in the same way.  In the terminal I get `The symbol: \[Pi]` verbatim (with the escaped `[Pi]` not the glyph π).  But I think QD wants the specified behavior *without* specific template insertion with `Message`.

Comment: I read the OP as wanting the appropriate version of 2D output (`OutputForm[]` for terminals and `StandardForm[]` for the usual front end) already embedded in the message itself, as opposed to being inserted there via the second and other arguments of `Message[]`.